# Free the counter variable when a while loop exits in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I've found that when making masses of objects in JavaScript, the `while` loop is the best tool to tune performance.

I get the best speed when writing my loop like this:

```
var i = array.length
while (i--) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

However, if I want to nest a while loop, I have to use a different variable name, otherwise the counter breaks:

```
var i = array1.length
while (i--) {
  var i = array2.length
  while (i--) {
    // NOPE THE COUNTER IS NOW BROKEN
  }
}
```

Some have suggested `j`, but then why not start the first array with a variable called `a` and go up form there?

What's the best practice in this situation?

Is there a way to `delete` the variable so it isn't available in the secondary scope?

Comment: Dont't see any problem, why is it hard to create two variables?

Comment: @Sergio: it can be annoying in automatically generated code

Comment: @Jackson -- For auto-generated code I'd use semi-random variable names... usually something like `$$_nameof_of_function_loopNumber`

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher: you still may need nested scopes if the variable is captured by a closure in the **do stuff** part (and you'd like **value capture** and not **variable capture**).

Comment: @6502 - True, but but the performance hit of an anonymous function in the middle of a loop is enough that I'd not recommend it until needed.  Hmm.. even then I doubt I'd recommend it and suggest just putting things in a named function to invoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `i` and `j` (followed by `k` if you are nesting that deep) are standard idioms shared by many programming languages.  (*In fact, the use of `i` as a loop variable goes back to `ForTran`.*)

By using `i` and `j`, anyone reading your code should realize those are standard loops and loop counters.  Using `a` makes the reader stop and ponder over "Why was that used?"

Now, to answer your question:

In Javascript, you could reuse the variable `i` if you wanted to by using an anonymous function - but this is

- Not standard practice
- An anti-pattern -- AKA dumb
- Slower to execute.

--

```
var i = 10;
while (i--) {
  (function() {
    // New function, this is a new `i`, completely masking the original.
    var i = 20;
    while(i--) {
    }
  {();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need variable scope here. In C, you can create variable scope with block:

```
int i = 1;
{
    int i = 2;
    printf("inner i = %d\n", i);
}
printf("outer i = %d\n", i);

//=>
inner i = 2
outer i = 1
```

However, in javascript, block doesn't create new variable scope, but shares the outer one. You'll need function to create a new variable scope.

```
var i = 2;
while (i--) {
    console.log("outer i = " + i);
    (function () {
        var i = 3;
        while (i--) {
            console.log("inner i = " + i);
        }
    })();
}

//=>
outer i = 1
inner i = 2
inner i = 1
inner i = 0
outer i = 0
inner i = 2
inner i = 1
inner i = 0
```

Comment: Cool answer! Very dirt, hahaha. Making a new function to keep a semantic variable name. JS is funny I like it.